# error: A value of type 'MaterialColor' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Color'. (invalid_assignment at [ipro] lib\Dashboard.dart:365)

Tags: flutter

I want to use chart so for that I put [this pakage](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter#-readme-tab-) in my pubspec.ymal after that these errors appear.

error: The argument type 'Color (where Color is defined in C:\Users\anasb\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\charts_common-0.8.1\lib\src\common\color.dart)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color (where Color is defined in C:\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\painting.dart)'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [ipro] lib\Dashboard.dart:159)

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwCzf.png)

Comment: as can be seen from your image, error has nothing to do with that package. it is all about InkWell Widget. Did you make sure that first letter in hexadecimal value is "0(ZERO)" no "o"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chart_flutter uses it's own Color class. So you can't use the SDK provided one.

See [this](https://github.com/google/charts/issues/130) issue on their repo.

### Solution 1:

You can use the following as a work around for custom colors until they fix this issue.

```
charts.Color.fromHex(code: '#f2f2f2')
```

---

### Solution 2:

Alternatively, you can define a custom function as follows, which converts the SDK provided color into chart.Color

```
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

charts.Color getChartColor(Color color) {
    return charts.Color(
        r: color.red,
        g: color.green,
        b: color.blue,
        a: color.alpha);
}
```

Then use it like

```
getChartColor(Colors.red)
```

Comment: my problem resolve...
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;